# jQuery.ajax() v1.5 returns "parsererror" for json data

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I have this function for getting a server id from a list. The function always returns "parsererror". I have looked at the JSON data returned but I cant seem to get it working, since jQuery have rewritten the ajax in v1.5.

```
function server_id()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/server_list.php",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data, status) {
             alert(status + "\n\n" + data.server_id);
        },
        complete: function(data, status){
                  alert(status);
        }
    });

}
```

server_list.php

```
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $output['server_id'] = '123';
    print json_encode($output);
```

In firebug Net >> XHR it reads it as JSON as it brings up the tab and the Response tab shows what is below.

```
{"server_id":"123"}
```

I have also tried setting the content type header like below but having no luck.

```
Content-type: application/json
```

**UPDATED**

I only get "parsererror" if the validation plugin is loaded from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation [docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) v1.7.

If you add the plug jquery automatically adds the jsonp callback to the query string even when you set to false or dont include the parms for jsonp. Very Strange

Any ideas on how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: please post the code snippet which generates this output

Comment: @pinusnegra edited post above to show output. Dont see the dif as you can see the firebug output which shows its JSON

Comment: Why is there a jsonpCallback? Is this supposed to be an AJAX request or JSONP?

Comment: @Dan Grossman As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

Comment: Try to put a break point in the `parseJSON()`/`ajaxConvert()` in jquery-1.5.js file and see what is happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want regular json communication (`dataType` is "json" instead of "jsonp" and `server_list.php` sends json), but you're setting `jsonp` options. Remove the `jsonp` and `jsonpcallback` lines. Setting `jsonp` to `false` does not mean you disable it!

When these two lines are commented out, [everything seems to work fine](http://phihag.de/2011/so/json/).

Comment: @philhag Thanks that help me narrow it down. I used the source in your link and I only get a parsererror if I have valifation plugin loaded from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation v1.7. Any ideas

Comment: @Claire Taylor: jquery-plugin-validation does not work with jquery 1.5; they did some really weird stuff with extend in their $.ajax shim. After refactoring this one weird line, it seems to work: http://phihag.de/2011/so/json/jquery.validate.js

Comment: Thank you very much for that info. I have decided to just remove the client-side validation. Thanks everyone who helped.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution here seems to be that jQuery 1.5 is not compatible with 1.7 of the validation plugin. Downgrading to jQuery 1.4.x (or otherwise patching or removing the validation plugin code as philhag suggested) solves the issue.

Huge thanks to those on this thread who identified the conflict. It saved me a bunch of headaches having to debug the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered for days before finding this thread, thanks to those who pointed at jQuery.validate as the culprit.

In my testing it actually seems to be jquery.validate-vsdoc.js which is causing the issue, not the plugin itself, in case that's of any use to anyone else.

Comment: `-vsdoc` files exist only to allow Visual Studios to do code completion - ["This file has been commented to support Visual Studio Intellisense."](http://code.google.com/p/jiangliang-project/source/browse/ZWW/ZWW/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js?r=14). There's no need to actually include them anywhere in your production site.

Comment: This seems like a comment to the question, rather than an answer, and it should be posted as such. To post a comment to a question you'll need to participate in the community and gain some reputation before you have the privilege. Welcome to SO!