# jQuery AJAX parsererror

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I am working on a small jQuery script which pulls json from a site on my domain. Have been working on it forever, and cant seem to get it. When I run the code with json as the "dataType" I get a status error of 0. However, when I put in jsonp, I get a status of 200 (OK), and a parsererror. The thing is, when I copy the contents of the json to a text file, I can grab it and parse it perfectly with "json" as the datatype. So, not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<script type ="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
url:"*blocked for security purposes*",
success: function(data){
    alert("Successful");
    console.log(data)
},
error: function(xhr, thrownError){
    console.log('ERROR: ' + thrownError);
    alert("status:" + xhr.status);
                alert("threw:" + thrownError);    }
}); });

</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: So, you get an error when it tries to parse some data that you haven't shared with us. That's not going to be easy to solve blind.

Comment: Well, I ran the code through jsonlint.com and it validated it as correct. Also, when I copy the contents into a text file and read it as json, it works as well. So, I know the code is well-formed JSON.

Comment: What's the content-type of the response?

Comment: did you mean to send your REQUEST as JSON?  contentType is what your are sending

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of various other qustions, see here for an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969486/289203

Basically, JSON-P is NOT json, instead, it's javascript which calls a function passing that function JSON.

E.g.

JSON response:

> {"a":"cat"}

JSON-P response:

> callmyjsonfunction({"a":"cat"})